# data binding is not updating view

Tags: android, mvvm

I am trying to update a view from my viewmodel class but it is not working. Here is my xml file

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="mainViewModel"
        type=".MainViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:elevation="4dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@color/base_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/personalNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_border"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(mainViewModel.personalNumber)}"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_border"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@{mainViewModel.location}"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ordersCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_border"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@{mainViewModel.ordersCount}"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_activity_buttons"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

MainViewModel class

```
public class MainViewModel extends BaseObservable {

private int ordersCount;

@Bindable
public int getPersonalNumber() {
    return MyApplication.getClientPreferences().getPersonalNumber();
}

@Bindable
public String getLocation() {
    return MyApplication.getClientPreferences().getLocation();
}

@Bindable
public String getOrdersCount(){
    return
```

MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getString(R.string.orders_count,ordersCount);
    }

```
public void setOrdersCount(int ordersCount) {
    this.ordersCount = ordersCount;
    notifyPropertyChanged(this.ordersCount);
    Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getInstance(), String.valueOf(ordersCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I tried to use Observable field for updating view from MainViewModel and it worked. But it is not working by extending MainViewModel from BaseObservable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use below property to update data:

```
notifyPropertyChanged(BR.ordersCount);
```

When Notify any listeners, BR is a generated class and BR.ordersCount update your value into Textview at runtime.

Also define like below:

```
<variable
        name="mainViewModel"
        type="com.app.YourAppName.MainViewModel" />
```

if in that any package is there then also define it's absolute path into it.

Also set value like below:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/ordersCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_border"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@={mainViewModel.ordersCount}"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

hope this helped you.

Comment: if this helps you then upvote it and successfull answer to it.

Comment: this worked. Actually i tried notifyPropertyChanged method but somehowe i couldn't find my property. After rebuilding project it worked.

Comment: where is notifyPropertyChanged() called?

Comment: @filthy-wizard Whenever you update your Textview then use your model and those likned model and set it then notifyPropertyChanged() used for update it.

Answer (score 3):

you might not have called

```
yourBindingObject.setMainViewModel(mainViewModelObj);
```

try this and let me know

Comment: it didn't work. I have already set viewmodel to binding object

Comment: you can also call notifyall on your model object it will work